# 100% Javascript Web Framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks

With the creation of node.js and various other utilities for writing server side javascript and with the MongoDB using javascript as it's primary access method, it looks like all the pieces for a web framework are now in place.

Are there any frameworks now using exclusively Javascript? (This means for server side interactions, database interactions, code generation, templating, possible MVC architecture)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across a couple when I was looking into nodejs platform. There is [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) and [spludo](http://spludo.com/). Although I haven't really used them on a project.